# passing a leaf of binary tree to a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

I create a class Node

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, isQuestion = False, left = None, right = None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = data
        self.isQuestion = isQuestion
```

and a function

```
def runTree(curNode):
    if (curNode is not None):
        if(curNode.isQuestion == True):
            print("\n\t")
            print(curNode.data)
            answer = input("\nEnter your input(1-yes, 0-no):\n")
            if(answer == '1'):
                runTree(curNode.right)
            elif(answer == '0'):
                runTree(curNode.left)

        else:
                print("\n\t")
                print(curNode.data)
```

when I call my function with 'runTree(curNode.left)' or 'runTree(curNode.right)' it doesn't access the leaf referenced by my root object, its creating a new object. How can I pass my left or right leaf and access that object in a function?

Comment: The code looks correct. I think the problem is not in above code, but in the code, that created the tree.

You can either use an interactive python debugger to step through your code or you add following  statements to your code.


first line of runTree() `print("calling runtree with %r" % curNode)`

and in order to get something readable add a __repr__ method to your Node class like:
`def __repr__(self):`
`return "Node(id=%s, data=%s, isq=%s, left=%s, right=%s)" % (id(self), self.data, self.isQuestion, id(self.left), id(self.right))`

Comment: I know the problem. When I pass root.right or root.left as reference to my function, it create a copy of that reference, not use the true object. But I don't know how fix it.

Comment: I repeat: runTree does definitely not create any copy.

Perhaps you post the code, that creates the example tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Here modified solution I replaced my old answer.

Please adapt your question, so that future readers understand to what I answered.

At the moment I answer to the answer that you gave to your own question, which might be confusing to others.

The main point is, that parameter passing does not exactly work as you expect it.

Python is a little particular and there are some good articles about this out there. Just don't remember the links.

Below adapted code creates an empty node before you call `runTree()`.
Then runTree() can change the object and add the question or answer.

```
# create a sentinel object to mark if Node is created without data
EMPTY = object()

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=EMPTY, isQuestion=False, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = data
        self.isQuestion = isQuestion

    def __repr__(self):
        return ( "Node(id=%s, data=%s, isq=%s, left=%s, right=%s)"
            % (id(self),
               self.data if self.data is not EMPTY else "empty",
               self.isQuestion,
               id(self.left) if self.left else None,
               id(self.right) if self.right else None))

root = Node("has wings?", True)

def runTree(curNode):
    print(curNode)
    # Node is never None, check only whether data has been filled in
    if (curNode.data is not EMPTY):
        if(curNode.isQuestion == True):
            print("\n\t")
            print(curNode.data)
            answer = input("\nEnter your input(1-yes, 0-no):\n")
            if(answer == '1'):
                if curNode.right is None:  # create child node if not existing
                    curNode.right = Node()
                runTree(curNode.right)
            elif(answer == '0'):
                if curNode.left is None: # create child node if not existing
                    curNode.left = Node()
                runTree(curNode.left)

        else:
                print("\n\t")
                print(curNode.data)

    else:
        print("\n###########################\nERROR: node isn't a question and not has a label yet.\n###########################\n")
        answer = input("Want to put a question(1) or a label(0)?\n")
        if(answer == '1'):
            question = input("write your question\n")
            # you could of course use method Node.change_node() instead if you want
            curNode.data = question
            curNode.isQuestion = True
            print(curNode)
            print(root)
        elif(answer == '0'):
            label = input("write your label\n")
            # you could of course use method Node.change_node() instead if you want
            curNode.data = label
            curNode.isQuestion = False
            print(curNode)
        print("\n\nrunning the decisionTree again\n###########################\n")
        print(root)

        # This creates a recursion step for every time you enter a new question
        # if you enter hundreds / thousands of questions you would encounter a python
        # error for exceeding the recursion depth.
        # But let's address this in another question or at elast with another answer
        runTree(root)

runTree(root)
```

Comment: this correct run correctly but it's create the tree in the code, My problem is when I was creating a new node in run time.

Comment: but the code does work, doesn't it?

What you tried to do initially doesn't work as python receives a reference to a None object and not as you expected a reference to curNode.right

If the code doesn't work please tell which inputs you had to type to make the code fail.

However I will probably only reply tomorrow.

Comment: what would be nice is if you could edit your question (post the correct code), so that others can follow up easier when searching lateron within stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my misunderstand gelonida

the whole code is it:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, isQuestion = False, left = None, right = None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = data
        self.isQuestion = isQuestion

root = Node("has wings?", True)

def runTree(curNode):
    if (curNode is not None):
        print(root.right)
        print(curNode)
        if(curNode.isQuestion == True):
            print("\n\t")
            print(curNode.data)
            answer = input("\nEnter your input(1-yes, 0-no):\n")
            if(answer == '1'):
                runTree(curNode.right)
            elif(answer == '0'):
                runTree(curNode.left)

        else:
                print("\n\t")
                print(curNode.data)

    else:
        print("\n###########################\nERROR: node isn't a question and not has a label yet.\n###########################\n")
        answer = input("Want to put a question(1) or a label(0)?\n")
        if(answer == '1'):
            question = input("write your question\n")
            curNode = Node(question, True)
            print(curNode)
            print(root)
        elif(answer == '0'):
            label = input("write your label\n")
            curNode = Node(label, False)
            print(curNode)
            print(root)
        print("\n\nrunning the decisionTree again\n###########################\n")
        runTree(root)

runTree(root)
```

Comment: the line at fault is `curNode = Node(question, True)`
Here you create a new node. what you want is to change the existing node.
`curNode.data = question` and 
`curNode.isQuestion = True`
same for answer == 0
`curNode.data = label`
and `curNode.isQuestion = False`

Comment: if possible it would be better to edit your question.
What you did now by accident is, that you  created an answer to your own question.

Just enhance your initial question.

Comment: pls ignore my first comment. it is not completely correct as you enter this section only if curNode is None. 
In fact the current node never attaches left and right nodes.

And now I undertstand what you mean with your comment "it create a copy of that reference, not use the true object"

Python does not work as you expect.

parameters are passed as a reference to the object that you pass.

so you have a reference to a None object and you cannot change this to a reference to a Node object.

WIll psot an answer in a few minutes

Comment: yes, thanks I understand it now. Python create a object inside the function with the same reference of that I pass as parameter. Because that, when I do curNode = Node() I overwrite my reference with a new object that not are root.right/left.